# checkbox disable/enable inquiry using javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and I have been Googling all day for this but I only found how to enable and disable one textbox using one checkbox. I tweaked the code a bit to work with what I want and here is what I got.  I'm thinking of instructing JS function to follow only the id of the checkbox, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Here is my code:

**JavaScript**

```
 <script>
 function enableText(checked){
     if(!checked){
         document.getElementById('sel1').disabled = true;
         document.getElementById('txt1').disabled = false;
     }
     else{
         document.getElementById('sel1').disabled = false;
         document.getElementById('txt1').disabled = true;
     }
 }
 function enableText(checked){
     if(!checked){
         document.getElementById('sel2').disabled = true;
         document.getElementById('txt2').disabled = false;
     }
     else{
         document.getElementById('sel2').disabled = false;
         document.getElementById('txt2').disabled = true;
     }
 }
 </script>
```

**HTML**

```
 <form name=sr2 method=post>
      <select name="pt" id="sel1">
           <option>test</option>
      </select>

      <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" checked="checked" onclick="enableText(this.checked)">
      Others

      <input type="text" name="pt" id="txt1" disabled="disabled">

      <select name="dept" id="sel2">
           <option>test</option>
      </select>

      <input type="checkbox" name="cb2" onclick="enableText(this.checked)"  checked="checked">
      Others

      <input type="text" name="dept" id="txt2" disabled="disabled">
 </form>
```

My question is how can I set the function in js to instruct `cb1` to only enable `txt1` and disable `sel1` and `cb2` to only enable `txt2` and disable `sel2`?  My code works but, for some reason, it enables `txt1` and `txt2` and disables `sel1` and `sel2` at the same time.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As a start, the two different functions that you are calling have the same name (`enableText`) . . . that is going to cause a conflict when executing.

Comment: @talemyn thanks for stating my mistake; Still working on my js so i was not aware about the conflict i made.

Comment: No worries . . . nobody here started out as an expert.   ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created two functions with the same name: `enableText`. Simplifying your code:

```
function enableText(checked, index){
     var sel = true, txt = false;

     if(checked) {
         sel = false;
         txt = true;
     }

     document.getElementById('sel' + index).disabled = sel;
     document.getElementById('txt' + index).disabled = txt;
}
```

And in your HTML:

```
onclick="enableText(this.checked, 1)"
```

And change the 2nd parameter for the next items.

A second version of your function with ternaries, but with the same purpose:

```
function enableText(checked, index) {
     document.getElementById('sel' + index).disabled = (checked ? false : true);
     document.getElementById('txt' + index).disabled = (checked ? true : false);
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a check and will update you in a few. :)

Comment: you nailed it! Thanks a lot :)